# jQuery live blur, isn't giving me the selector(e)

Tags: jquery

```
$('.comment_reply').live('focus', function() {
    var textArea = $(this).find('.comment_content');
}).live('blur', function(e) {

    var textArea = $(this).find('.comment_content');

    if (textArea.val().length === 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Hi, I'm using the above for a comment box. When a user clicks out of the comment box and hasn't entered anything I want to hide the comment box. Issue is, with the live blur, I am not getting the selector of the textarea either via e or this, where with live focus I do.

Ideas?

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for [me](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/EEZVe/) (on chrome 9)

What's your HTML like ? What browsers are you targeting?